# C# Calendar Grid (Appointment Control)

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, controls

I wanted to ask whether there's a control like a big grid calendar that we can use to manage all the appointments. Like in our cell phone we have calendar and we can save reminders, birthdays, etc. I'm looking for same thing but for the desktop & its size should be at least 600x400. [image: big grid calendar]

When the users clicks an individual date the details should be shown.

Is there any control like that available?

Comment: have you made a calendar control of your own, i am willing to know what you used or how you did it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Calendar controls that might have a view that looks like what you need. For example
[BetterCalendar](http://bettercalendar.codeplex.com/) - which is free, open source and pretty nice. Or you can use any of the commercial controls like the one from [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winschedule.aspx#Overview).

Comment: Thanks, I think "BetterCalender" will do the job for me..You saved me alot of time because I was thinking of making the control myself :).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Devexpress components - they provide a good calendar control and also a range of layout controls you could use for the appointment grid.